# Filter sending blank messages from contact form 7

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, textarea

I want to integrate this code to my contact form 7 in additional setting:

```
on_sent_ok: " if (document.getElementById("textArea1").value.trim() == '') {alert("no Message");}"
```

the logic is supposed to be like this:

```
if textarea1 == " " alert message not to send the message else send the message
```

And in putting my code: when I tried to put some "        " blank spaces and sent it , a message:

"your message sent successfully" - appeared after the alert pop up message("no Message") and then check my email the blank spaces was sent.I am planning not to send some blank spaces when someone attempt to send blank spaces.
How could I solve this problem?How to filter when blank spaces only sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `jQuery` you can trim your space by use of `$.trim()` function.

```
if($.trim($("#textArea1").val()) == "")
{
  alert(" message not to send the message");
}
else 
{
  alert("Message sent successfully");
}
```

Comment: how could I integrate it in wordpress to contact form 7? I am newbie to jquery .. please help